# How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site I recently upgraded. The old site had a calendar that created hundreds of pages, on the new site this has been replaced by an events page and those calendar URL's no longer exist. For months now I have been getting search engines pounding no longer existent pages like these ones.

For example:

```
page not found calendar-for-groups/2012-09-15/1093
page not found calendar-for-groups/2011-W09/77
page not found calendar-for-groups/2011-W27/77
page not found calendar-for-groups/2012-06-29/1093
```

How can I use htaccess to redirect any `www.mywebsite.com/calendar-for-groups/*` request to `www.mywebsite.com/events`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use the `RedirectMatch` directive of `mod_alias`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/calendar-for-groups/.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/events
```

Or with `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteRule ^calendar-for-groups/ http://www.mywebsite.com/events [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions so far and...
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/calendar-for-groups/.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/events`
worked like a charm. Thanks a million!

Comment: Hello @Floern Will this work in a buddypress site where I want to redirect all links going to any user but instead of the default tab, I want to choose a different tab. The current default tab leaves the body of the profile page blank. I want to redirect to the activity page. it is going to a profile page but doesn't choose the tab by default.

Answer (score 10):

You can do with a few rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^calendar-for-groups/(.*)   /events [R=301,L]
```