# How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character one directory below

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

is a htaccess 301 redirect possible with this url?

```
www.example.com/en/job/viewcompany/company-x/nav-35
```

I want to redirect above url to the one below, eliminating 'nav-35' from it

```
www.example.com/en/job/viewcompany/company-x
```

NOTE: Company-x can be any company name. Depends on which that has been fetched from the DB

Found this example but wasn't applicable in my case:
[How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877486/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-redirect-paths-with-a-wildcard-character)

Sorry. Forgot to mention that

```
www.example.com/en/job/viewcompany/company-x/nav-35
```

is also a redirect from

```
www.example.com/en/job/viewcompany/cat-x/company-x/nav-35
```

as below

```
Redirect 301 /en/job/viewcompany/cat-x/  http://example.com/en/job/viewcompany/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/nav-\d+/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but didn't work. Could it be because the url is already a redirect?

Comment: No, I think it indicates site language: English. it's a Joomla site. This is how the original url structure looked like

/en/component/componentname/company/viewcompany/cat-x/company-x/nav-32


-- Removed 'component', 'componentname' and 'company' by redirecting to

/en/job/viewcompany/cat-x/company-x/nav-32


-- then removed 'category number' by  redirecting to 

/en/job/viewcompany/company-x/nav-32

Now I want to remove nav-32 from it.

--Joomla CMS--

Comment: http://www.itandtelecomkenya.com/en/job/viewcompany/cat-57/company-farm-concern-international-fci-20/nav-35        and  http://www.itandtelecomkenya.com/en/job/viewcompany/cat-57/company-farm-concern-international-fci-20/ all land on the same page. In google webmasters i'm getting duplicate description. Also both urls canonical.

Comment: I want all urls with a nav- at the end to redirect to ones that do not. Like in the urls i've given above. I want the first one to be redirected to the second one