# Adding $ on redirect stops working, rewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**PHP Version 5.4.16**

**Apache Loaded modules**

```
core mod_so http_core mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_anon mod_authn_core mod_authn_dbd mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_file mod_authn_socache mod_authz_core mod_authz_dbd mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_owner mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_data mod_dbd mod_deflate mod_dir mod_dumpio mod_echo mod_env mod_expires mod_ext_filter mod_filter mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_log_config mod_logio mod_mime_magic mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_remoteip mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_slotmem_plain mod_slotmem_shm mod_socache_dbm mod_socache_memcache mod_socache_shmcb mod_status mod_substitute mod_suexec mod_unique_id mod_unixd mod_userdir mod_version mod_vhost_alias mod_dav mod_dav_fs mod_dav_lock mod_lua prefork mod_proxy mod_lbmethod_bybusyness mod_lbmethod_byrequests mod_lbmethod_bytraffic mod_lbmethod_heartbeat mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_express mod_proxy_fcgi mod_proxy_fdpass mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_scgi mod_proxy_wstunnel mod_ssl mod_systemd mod_cgi mod_php5
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to redirect some pages from my website to the home of another website, but I can't seem to make it work.
Currently i have this:

```
redirect 301 /portalwebhttp://www2.tha.com.br
```

It works if the url is exactly `www.oldwebsite.com.br/portalweb`.But if add anything after the `portalweb` it redirects to this: `http://www.mywebsite.com.br/anything`

I have tried the following solutions:

```
redirect 301 /portalweb$ http://www.mywebsite.com.br

Redirect "/portalweb$" "http://www.mywebsite.com.br/"

RedirectMatch ^portalweb/$ http://www.mywebsite.com.br

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    "^portalweb$"  "http://www.mywebsite.com.br/" [R,L]
RewriteRule    "^portalweb/$"  "http://www.mywebsite.com.br/" [R,L]
```

When i add any of the solutions above, it just doesn't work at all. It seems that the `$` character make the redirect not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a wild card https://stackoverflow.com/q/6877486/4139335

Comment: @MichaelWarner - His problem was not exactly the same as mine, i don't want the following url to be redirect as well, but i manage to resolve my problem by adding a 301 on the `RedirectMatch`. I'll post a answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! Just to be clear I was not saying it was the same question but this technique might help that's all.

Comment: @MichaelWarner - Yes haha, I'm sorry if implied that, it was not my 
intention. Do you know why the `301` solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, as exampled [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

`Redirect` default status code is 302 as explained [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

If you change the status code to 301 this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer [stackoverflow.com/q/6877486/4139335](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6877486/4139335) that was sugested by @MichaelWarner. I notice that i was missing a `301` in my `RedirectMatch`

This worked:
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/portalweb/$ https://www.mywebsite.com.br`
I don't know why the `301` did the trick, if someone explain it to me, i would be glad.